# Proving 'All multiples of 10 are even numbers'

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I made 2 equations:

$A = \{n:n=10k \text{ for some } k∈N\}$

$B = \{n:n=2j \text{ for some } j∈N\}$

I solved for the equation if it is possible, so I wrote:

$2j = 10k$

I used an arbitrary value using $k = 2$

so: $2j = 10(2)$

$j = 10$

And I made a check by using the $j$ value in the same equation

$2(10) = 10k$

$k = 2$

the results are the same when I substituted the $k$ value in the same equation again.

Thus, $B$ is a subset of $A$.

Is my proving logic correct, or is there a best way to prove this?

Edit: fixed $k = 1$ to $k = 2$

Comment: $10k=2\cdot (5k)$. What elso do you need?

Answer (score 2):

Another way to prove this is to take a number $x$ that is a multiple of $10$, so we can write $x = 10k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then it follows that $x = 10k = 2*5k = 2k'$, where $k' = 5k$, so $x$ is an even number. Since $x$ was chosen arbitrarily, all numbers that are a multiple of $10$ must be even.

Comment: I don't understand how $10k$ became $2k′$. Or did you just factor $10k$?

Comment: @user231871 , $k^{\shortmid}=5k$.